# R vctrs subclassing with unicity constraint

Tags: r, vctrs

In R, I need to define a subclass of `vctrs` with an unicity constraint.
I can propose here a minimal code for such new `uid` vector type.

```
library(vctrs)

new_uid <- function(x) {
  if (anyDuplicated(x) > 0) stop("Duplicated id")
  new_vctr(x,class="uid")
}

uid <- function(length=0) {
  new_uid(0:(length-1))
}

vec_type2.uid.uid <- function(x,y, ...)  uid()
vec_type2.uid.uid <- function(x, to, ...) x
```

I can create vectors of that type

```
x <- new_uid(1:10)
y <- new_uid(11:20)
```

and if I have duplicated values an error is produced

```
z <- new_uid(c(1:10,2))
Error in new_uid(c(1:10, 2)) : Duplicated id
```

The concatenation works and produces a longer `uid` vector

```
vec_c(x,y)
<uid[20]>
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

But if it creates duplicates, the constraint is not asserted and
therefore, no error is raised.

```
vec_c(x,x)
<uid[20]>
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

As proposed by @Rui-Barradas `base::c` can be specialized,

```
c.uid <- function(...){
  x <- unlist(list(...))
  #x <- unique(x)
  new_uid(x)
}

c(x, x)
# Error in new_uid(x) : Duplicated id
```

But this does not impact the `vctrs::vec_c()` function used by `tibble`...

Can I define something to force the assertion of the unicity constraint after concatenation using `vec_c` ?

All the best,

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that the following is what you want, I have (very) little experience with vctrs classes.

```
c.uid <- function(...){
  x <- unlist(list(...))
  #x <- unique(x)
  new_uid(x)
}

c(x, x)
# Error in new_uid(x) : Duplicated id
```

Comment: I did that, but it works only with `c()` but not with `vec_c()` and therefore not with `tibble` manipulations :-(.
Nevertheless, thank you for the proposition

Answer (score 0):

After looking again into the `vctrs` vignette *S3 vectors*, I tested a solution that works.

It requires to define a `vec_restore.uid` method that will assert the unicity,
before passing to the `NextMethod` usually the default one :

```
vec_restore.uid <- function(x, to, ...) {
  if (anyDuplicated(na.omit(x)) > 0)
    stop("Duplicated id")
  NextMethod()
}
```

after that we get the correct behaviour

```
vec_c(x,x)
Error in vec_restore.uid(x = x, to = to, n = n) : Duplicated id
```

and the same with

```
c(x,x)
Error in vec_restore.uid(x = x, to = to, n = n) : Duplicated id
```

while

```
c(x,y)
<uid[20]>
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

continues to provide the correct answer.

Thank you for your help.